# Все пропало и появилась ошибка syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'?

Tags: yii2, yii

```
<?= GridView::widget([
     'dataProvider' = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => HistoryBalance::find()
        ->andWhere(['user_id' => $id])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
        ->limit(30)
        ->all(),
]),
```

Comment: Судя по этому кусочку кода, Вы забыли закрыть widget([. Поставьте ]) после последней запятой.

Answer (score 2):

Не `=`, а `=>`:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
     'dataProvider' => new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => HistoryBalance::find()
        ->andWhere(['user_id' => $id])
        ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
        ->limit(30)
        ->all(),
]),
```

Comment: Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Поле **query** в объекта **ActiveDataProvider** принимаєт объект клаcа **\yii\db\Query**, а вы пытались скормить ему уже готовый массив объектов

```
<?= GridView::widget(
     [
         'dataProvider' => new ActiveDataProvider(
              [
                  'query' => HistoryBalance::find()
                       ->andWhere(['user_id' => $id])
                       ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
                       ->limit(30),
              ]    

     ]
);
?>
```